# Append array key value to a session array

Tags: php, arrays, session

Want to append a key and value to the already created session.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {

                $bag = array(
                        "sessionId" => session_id(),
                        "productId" => $productId, 
                        "size"      => $productSize,
                        "quantity"  => $productQuantity
                    );

                $_SESSION['cart'] = $bag;

            } else {

                $_SESSION['cart']['sessionId'] = session_id();
                $_SESSION['cart']['productId'] = $productId;
                $_SESSION['cart']['size'] = $productSize;
                $_SESSION['cart']['quantity'] = $productQuantity;

            }
```

If session has already been created, then append the new variables to the session with its keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SESSION['cart']` should be an array of items, not a single item as you've written it. Each item will be a separate associative array, which you push onto the cart array.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}
$bag = array(
    "sessionId" => session_id(),
    "productId" => $productId, 
    "size"      => $productSize,
    "quantity"  => $productQuantity
);
$_SESSION['cart'][] = $bag;
```